# Unable to access the remote intranet after OpenVPN connection

Tags: vpn, ubuntu-18.04

I need to use OpenVPN to connect to the company's intranet. After my installation, the client can show that the connection is successful, but I can only access the Ubuntu virtual machine where the OpenVPN server is located. Other virtual machines in the Intranet can't be connected. Many methods have been tried but they can't be solved. Please ask how to solve this problem. The configuration of the server and the client is as follows:

Server:

```
port 1110
proto tcp
dev tun
ca keys/ca.crt
cert keys/server.crt
key keys/server.key  
dh keys/dh2048.pem
server 10.0.8.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist /var/log/openvpn/ipp.txt
push "route 10.0.8.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0"
duplicate-cn
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
max-clients 100
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
log         /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
log-append  /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
verb 3
auth-user-pass-verify /etc/openvpn/checkpsw.sh via-env
username-as-common-name
script-security 3
```

Client:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote 147.153.37.160  1110
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 3
auth-user-pass pass.txt
```

Iptables:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:1110 /* openvpn */

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  10.6.0.0/24          anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.6.0.0/24         
ACCEPT     all  --  10.0.8.0/24          anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.0.8.0/24         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Do the intranet servers know about the VPN network? They should route packages destined for `10.0.8.0/24` through the VPN server. Also, the VPN server must have IPv4 forwarding enabled, it might worth checking that as well.

Comment: I have configured route forwarding in the router, opened port 147.153.37.160 1110, and found a warning message in the log file. Will this warning affect my access?

Comment: WARNING: Bad encapsulated packet length from peer (18245), which must be > 0 and <= 1627 -- please ensure that --tun-mtu or --link-mtu is equal on both peers -- this condition could also indicate a possible active attack on the TCP link -- [Attempting restart...]